# Автоматическое создание переменных

Tags: c++

Вот допустим, у меня есть ввод данных C++:
1 2 3 4 5...n
n - нефиксированное значение
Числа вводятся через пробел
Мне надо, чтобы создались переменные с именами a1,a2,a3,a4,...,an соответственно, то есть, a1 равно 1, a2 - 2, an - n, как это реализовать?

Comment: Для этого надо использовать другой язык.

Вопрос можно? А нафига?

Comment: для таких целей надо использовать массивы или шаблоны(динамические массивы)

Comment: похоже на китайский код - вместо создания массива из n чисел создается n переменных))

Comment: Возможно ТС нужны какие-то структури типа пар имя-значение. Но пока сам не сознается, гадать бесполезно.

@DreamChild только вот неописанные заранее переменные в C/C++ существовать не могут.

Comment: вероятно, ТС писал  хелловорлды на каком-нибудь php/js и, пытаясь перейти на плюсы, не может отвыкнуть от того, что в вышеуказанных языках можно было  все, и за это ничего не было

Comment: >только вот неописанные заранее переменные в C/C++ существовать не могут 

разумеется, я в курсе, и нигде не утверждал обратное

Comment: А как вы собираетесь потом пользоваться этими переменными в остальном коде?

Делайте как все, заведите массив и не морочьте нам голову.

Comment: IMHO TC просто еще нигде не читал о массивах.

Comment: Конечно, в С++ в рантайме новые переменные создавать не получится. Для решения указанной проблемы так и напрашивается `vector`.

Comment: @skegg, опубликуйте свой комментарий как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Берем создаем файл cpp записываем туда переменные, после чего его подключаем этот файл, и у нас есть переменные записанные в этом файле как код программы.

Comment: А примерчик не продемонстрируете?

Comment: @alexlz, ну очевидно же как :) Нафига такое извращение - другой вопрос.

Comment: Я таким извращением не занимаюсь, я предложил идею извращения автору вопроса, а пример не буду приводить так как это извращение.
P.S. Не понимаю почему минуют за идею…

Comment: >Не понимаю почему минусуют за идею…

Потому что идиотская (btw, я не минусовал, мне просто смешно)

Comment: Мне кажется, в этой идее есть привкус благородного безумия. Кодогенерация под задачу -- не такая плохая идея.

+1 от меня.

Comment: @VladD, манипуляторы :)

Comment: Да, идея изучить данные и сгенерить код, обрабатывающий их нетрадиционная. Тоже плюсую.

Но вот сможет ли, незнакомый с массивами ТС, реализовать ее?

Comment: Добавил пример с кодогенерацией отдельным ответом.

Answer (score 2):

Отталкиваясь от идеи [[@good](/users/7736/good)](/users/7736/good), вот вам пример с кодогенерацией:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const char* namePrefix = "a";
const char* indent = "    ";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int value;
    int n;
    cout << "inline int sum()" << endl;
    cout << "{" << endl;
    for (n = 0; cin >> value; n++)
        cout << indent << "int " << namePrefix << n << " = " << value << ";" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << indent << "return " << namePrefix << "0";
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        cout << " + " << namePrefix << i;
    cout << ";" << endl;
    cout << "}" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Для входной информации

> 11 22 33 44 55

производит такой вот исходник:

```
inline int sum()
{
    int a0 = 11;
    int a1 = 22;
    int a2 = 33;
    int a3 = 44;
    int a4 = 55;

    return a0 + a1 + a2 + a3 + a4;
}
```

Разумеется, пример упрощён, но, я думаю, вы легко подстроите его под свои нужды и допилите необходимую инфраструктуру (шаблоны, автоматизация, анализ). Такой подход может рассматриваться как альтернатива достаточно сложному в поддержке и требовательному к квалификации участников проекта [TMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming).

---

Небольшой комментарий на тему "для чего это нужно": из личной практики, мне нужно было как-то вычислять много (миллионов) раз значения интерполяционного полинома в различных точках. Коэффициенты полинома получались в результате долгих предварительных вычислений в зависимости от входных данных. Простой подход -- записать коэффициенты в массив и при получении значения применять схему Горнера -- был не так уж и плох, но разворачивание полинома в выражение при помощи аналогичной кодогенерации позволило сэкономить управление циклом и повысить скорость вычислений в полтора раза, что не так уж и плохо для настолько элементарного трюка.

Comment: А можно ведь и упростить до генерации


   #define NUMBERS_SUM (11+22+33+44+55)

Comment: @avp: в таком простом случае -- да, однако для более сложных вариантов нужен предварительный анализ. Например, если к-во входных элементов маленькое, генерируется insertion sort, если большое -- quicksort, и т. п. Так что мой код "на вырост".

Comment: А я и не спорю. Просто показал другой вариант (в котором имена переменных оказались уже не нужны).

Comment: @avp: в любом случае вычисление уходит из времени выполнения на время компиляции.

Comment: @VladD Поскольку, по условиям задачи, вся эта канитель происходит во время выполнения, то об экономии времени говорить точно не стоит.

Answer (score 1):

Используй массивы. Они созданы именно для хранения ряда подобных значений.

Answer (score -2):

можно так, но количество переменных, как и во всех предыдущих ответах, ограниченное.

```
#define concat(head, tail) head ## tail
```

тогда в случае с concat(a, 1) будет создана переменная a1

Comment: Вопрошающему требуется не сборка строки в режиме компиляции, а хранение заранее неопределённого количества элементов — это к динамическому массиву.